# How to retrieve a created entry from outside using Angular-redux store

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, observable

#### The context

I'm using a basic store ecosystem with actions, epics, reducers using [angular-redux store](https://github.com/angular-redux/store).

To summarize quickly :
[little graph of my store](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6373178/28621282-b7a24360-7210-11e7-93e1-9a10782d35d3.jpg)

My state

```
state
|_ accounts
  |_ items
  |_ paginations
  |_ loading
  |_ errors
|_ applications
  |_ items
  |_ paginations
  |_ loading
  |_ errors
```

So my component, on a creation entry is calling the corresponding action. (I removed the non-necessary code)

```js
export class ApplicationNewComponent  implements OnInit {

  private application;

  constructor(private collection: CollectionActions) {}

  onSubmit() {
    this.collection.createEntry(COLLECTION_TYPES.APPLICATION, {}, this.application);
    };
}
```

The `CollectionActions` `dispatch` the action.
The `reducer` checks if he has something to do on the `state`.
The `epics` receive the action, do all the required checks before calling the service API if needed, then depending on the answer, will call the corresponding action, and the `reducer` will act, update the state.
Nothing really new for redux user.

From my `ApplicationListComponent`, I only subscribe to the applications.items, from my `ApplicationDetailComponent` I'm subscribing to a specific item of this list, etc.

#### The Problem

My problem is that from the `ApplicationNewComponent` that should create an entry, I don't know what I could do to retrieve only the new entry in a clean way.

With my current store behavior and without watching the whole collection to compare a previous and a new state, I don't know how to **inform my ApplicationNewComponent that the entry has been created and has the id 14.** (as an example)

The easiest way I see actually to solve my issue is to add a new key in the state, called something like 'lastCreatedEntry', use the reducer to fill it with a part of the API answer and subscribe to it in my component.

is there a way to retrieve only the state diff from outside the store ?

is there a way to watch the actions flow and not the state ?

is there already something for this kind of situation ?

Any advice/help is really welcome.
I'm maybe mistaken on many points, please forgive my poor english also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `angular-redux` but `ngrx` instead but i believe the principle should be the same. in your component you probably do subscribe to the part of the store that keeps the colletion. not necessarily the whole one, as in general case it might be a PagedCollection and your newly created one falls out of the current page shown.

You didn't specify, what does your component actually do? Does it show collections or you want to show update screen of last created entity or?

Now, your flow depends actually on your particular component and needs. When you say you need *ID to do some other calls*, what does that actually mean? Are those calls necessary to be done from component or do they maybe better fit into epics, for example?

If its, for example, update entity screen the one you want to show then you would setup your component route something like `component/{entityId}` and you would redirect to that route from your epic using the entityId that epic got from server.

as you can see, it is highly dependant on what you want to do in component and your UX flow.

**[UPDATE]**
Regarding 'direct communication between epic and dumb control'... that is exactly what you don't want to have. Usual setup is like this:

1. You have CreateComponent
2. After user finished input and submits, your dispatch an action, epic picks up, fires service.createNewRequest() which returns `newlyCreatedId`
3. Your epic now knows your newlyCreatedId returned by the service and it does router.navigate('applicationDetailsComponent/newlyCreatedId')
4. You have your applicationDetailsComponent (both, smart and dumb, of course) and route defined for it (route definition includes {id})
5. You have a guard with canActivate for that route and in the guard you fire a new request service.getApplicationById(id)
6. Completion of that action is picked up by reducer which updates part of the store named something like `selectedApplication'
7. Your `applicationDetailsComponent` is subscribed to `selectedApplication' part of the store

You could select entity from collection you already have in the store instead of firing request in 5. but its not a good idea because of the paged collections. If you have paged collections (which is kept in store) and your newly created entity falls out of current page then you have a problem. So its a better idea to go with separate request.

**[UPDATE 2]**
If you want to have both things (create/edit) in the same component then yes, you would have part of the store named `selectedEntity` and fill it with last created one. I name it `selectedEntity` on purpose because the moments its created on server, its not addNewComponent anymore but editComponent one. And in that one you would subscribe to `selectedEntity` part of the store. But then, you might create confusion because if you route to that component, you'll have to flag it somehow is it in createNew mode (nothing saved yet) or is it in edit mode (something created and you're looking at existing entity).

Comment: You have a point, I'm not clear enough.
On my differents component I'm not watching the whole state but a specific collection. I have updated my post to show the state.

Comment: As you said, for my applicationListComponent, I only subscribe to the applications.items, and for my applicationDetailComponent I'm subscribing to a specific item of this list.

Comment: My problem is that from the applicationNewComponent that should create an entry, I don't know on what I could subscribe to retrieve only the new entry in a clean way.
To answer you about the "other calls", it's about adding some relations for my created application. It's a really specific behavior for this ressource and
for the moment I would prefer to not put this in my generic store.

Comment: "you would redirect to that route from your epic using the entityId that epic got from server."
That's my problem, I have no direct communication between epics and dumb components.

Comment: so if i understand correctly, you have 2 components: `applicationNewComponent` where user fills in something, it triggers epics and you get result from server and then you have `applicationDetailsComponent` which is triggered after epic gets response from server that new entity was created. and in that `applicationDetailsComponent` you want to subscribe to newly created one. is that correct ux flow? and if so, is your applicationDetailComponent a modal window or regular screen?

Comment: So you are right, in my ApplicationNewComponent, the user fill a form, then the component call the collectionAction that dispatch the action and the epics&reducers&friends are triggered. I would like to retrieve the created entry inside the ApplicationNewComponent, there is no need to think about the other components around. Thanks for the time you are taking for my question.
What I'm actually doing to solve my issue, is to add a key "item" inside a ressource of my state, and put the current/created item inside it. So I can subscribe on it from outside

Comment: _"3. Your epic now knows your newlyCreatedId returned by the service and it does router.navigate('applicationDetailsComponent/newlyCreatedId')_
I didnt think about giving the epics the power to use the router, that's a nice way to solve my problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: well, that's exactly what they are for > side effects. and changing a route based on servers response is typical side effect. i don't know if angular-redux has some router implementation or not. but if not, you just inject router into your epic and use `router.navigate`...